# Linear mapping $l$ vanishes at $x_0$ faster than $|x-x_0|$ if and on only if $l=0$

Tags: analysis

I need proof verification, any feedback will be appreciated, thank you.
I have to prove that $l\in Hom(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{m})$ vanishes at $x_0$ faster than $|x-x_0|$ if and only if $l=0$.

If $l=0$ then the claim is pretty obvious. I am not sure of the other part of my proof, so this is how I did it.

I said let's assume that $l\neq 0$, which means there exists $z\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$  such that $l(z)\neq 0$ .So according to our assumption, $\underset{x\rightarrow x_{0}}{lim}\frac{\left|l(x-x_{0})\right|}{\left|x-x_{0}\right|}=0$ . But since $l$ is continuous, it's the same as sayin $\underset{h\rightarrow 0}{lim}\frac{\left|l(hz)\right|}{\left|zh\right|}=0$

But since the mapping is linear we will get $\underset{h\rightarrow0}{lim}\frac{\left|l(hz)\right|}{\left|hz\right|}=\underset{h\rightarrow0}{lim}\frac{|h|\cdot|l(z)|}{|h|\cdot|z|}=\underset{h\rightarrow0}{lim}\frac{|l(z)|}{|z|}\neq0$ Which is clearly a contradiction.

Is this a correct proof? My main problem was to justify that $\underset{x\rightarrow x_{0}}{lim}\frac{\left|l(x-x_{0})\right|}{\left|x-x_{0}\right|}=\underset{h\rightarrow0}{lim}\frac{\left|l(hz)\right|}{\left|hz\right|}$

The fact that $l$ is continuous is enough to justify that? Thanks!

Comment: $0=\lim_{\mathbb{R}^n\ni x\to x_0}\frac{|l(x-x_0)|}{|x-x_0|}=\lim_{\mathbb{R}^n\ni x\to0}\frac{|l(x)|}{|x|}$. If this limit exists, then moving $x$ to $0$ along an specific direction also exists and is the same value. Therefore $0\lim_{\mathbb{R}\ni h\to0}\frac{|l(hz)|}{|hz|}=\frac{|l(z)|}{|z|}$.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I just realized that the continuity of $l$ has nothing to do with the equality of the two limits, Thanks!

Comment: This argument seems OK if it happens that $x_0=0,$ the origin of the vector space. However IMO some extra set-up is needed to adapt the argument in case $x_0 \neq 0,$ maybe via defining another map.